# Data type used to accept only alphabetic value using stored procedure in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to accept only alphabetic value

Comment: Good answers below )

Answer (score 0):

Using constraint to accept only alphabetic values :

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT column_alpha_check
CHECK
(
  Column_Name like '%[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%'
)
```

Comment: There may be problems with check constraint see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132644/sql-check-constraint-not-working-properly, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working. I note that mariadb 10.2.1 supposedly does support check constraints. Don't know about mysql.