# Unable to add check constraint to a column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a simple table with a few columns. I would like to add a check constraint to one of the columns, see below:

```
create table jobs (
    JOB_ID varchar(10) not null,
    JOB_TITLE varchar(35) not null,
    MIN_SALARY decimal(6,0),
    MAX_SALARY decimal(6,0) 
    CHECK(MAX_SALARY<=25000)
    );
```

This returns an error for the `CHECK` line.

> A comma or closing bracket was expected. (near CHECK)

If I add a comma like to the previous line; `MAX_SALARY decimal(6,0),`, I am returned with more errors:

> A symbol name was expected! A reserved keyword can not be used as a column name without backquotes.
>
> Unexpected beginning of statement near MAX_SALARY
>
> Unexpected beginning of statement near 25000

Comment: Your Database server is ??

Comment: @Hackit I'm new to this so I'm not too sure on the terminology. But I am running phpMyAdmin via xampp

Comment: ok Fine Its `MYSQL` !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql CHECK constraint not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132644/sql-check-constraint-not-working-properly) MySQL does not support check constraints!

Comment: First Just Create The Simple Table And Then Using Alter Try to Add Check like as update my ans !!

Comment: I'm just so lost here, this is an example given to me by my tutor and it doesn't work.

Comment: may i know the database engine type

Comment: @Hackit As Lord Peter has said, I believe MySQL does not support check constraint,

Comment: @AugustWilliams Yes ! `CHECK` constraints are not supported by MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated:**

**Just Create Table Without CHECK and Then After Alter it:**

```
  create table jobs (
    JOB_ID varchar(10) not null,
    JOB_TITLE varchar(35) not null,
    MIN_SALARY decimal(6,0),
    MAX_SALARY decimal(6,0)
    );
```

---

```
ALTER TABLE jobs ADD CHECK (MAX_SALARY<=25000);
```

---

**OR**

---

**In MySQL:**

```
create table jobs (
    JOB_ID varchar(10) not null,
    JOB_TITLE varchar(35) not null,
    MIN_SALARY decimal(6,0),
    MAX_SALARY decimal(6,0), 
    CHECK(MAX_SALARY<=25000)    
    );
```

---

**SQL Server / Oracle**

```
 create table jobs (
    JOB_ID varchar(10) not null,
    JOB_TITLE varchar(35) not null,
    MIN_SALARY decimal(6,0),
    MAX_SALARY decimal(6,0) CHECK(MAX_SALARY<=25000)

    );
```

---

**NOTE:** `CHECK` constraints are not supported by `MySQL` But You Can Use it, as i declared , but its not give you an output !!

Comment: All of these examples return me with similar errors.

Comment: @AugustWilliams Can You Try With Alter table ?

Comment: `CHECK` conflict with `ADD`

Comment: @AugustWilliams Its Completely Work On My Local !!