# How can I see or edit the list of check constraints in PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm unable to find a place in PHPMyAdmin to see the list of check constraints.

I'm not talking about foreign key constraints, neither do I talk about indexes (unique or non-unique).

I want to manage check constraints.

I select a table, and go to `Structure` tab. There I can see the columns. I can move columns. I can manage indexes. I can go to `Relation view` and manage foreign keys. But I can't find a link or tab to manage **check constraints**.

Comment: Back in 2017 this was not supported (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46747370/724039 ). I think the development of phpMyAdmin did not catch up on these new features?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to add check constraint to a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46747330/unable-to-add-check-constraint-to-a-column)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be supported by phpmyadmin.

But you can try :

> SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;

(with fulltext option checked)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Information Schema in PhpmyAdmin and click 'Check Constraints'

[image]